# Duplicate entries in 'All apps' list

Tags: applications

I started to have for some reasons duplicated entries in 'All apps'. For many apps it was not a problem but one of apps is Google Maps - how to get rid of the problem without:

- Restoring to factory defaults
- Uninstalling Google Maps permanently

**Edit**: My phone is HTC Wildfire from 3 (to respond to comment).

Comment: model, manufacturer, and carrier please

Comment: Are these apps that are to replace built-in apps? If so there may be nothing for it.

Comment: @Al Everett: sorry - I do not understend.

Comment: Are you using mods or stock Android? What Android version? Did you install alternative updates (e.g. Brut's map hack, etc)? Generally, there can only be duplicate entry in menu if the application is installed under different identifier (e.g. com.google.android.apps.maps and brut.googlemaps for example)

Comment: Stock 2.1 android without any hacks or rooting. It is gone now after uninstalling one of app with duplicated entry.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall one of the duplicate apps

Comment: I realize this is an old answer, but I have this problem on 4.0 (LG Optimus G) and uninstalling one uninstalled both. The app isn't installed twice, just double entries in the apps list.  Rebooting resolved the issue.